# Filter search with AngularJs not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to adapt the following search filter seen [here](http://codepen.io/asadfida/pen/znmCq) but with little sucesss. What am I getting wrong?

This is my code so far:

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['starter.services'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
})

.controller('SearchCtrl', ["$scope", "ServicesData", function($scope, ServicesData, filterFilter)  {

  // Get list items

  $scope.categoryList = ServicesData.getAllCategories();
  $scope.serviceList = ServicesData.getAllServices();
  $scope.businessList = ServicesData.getAllBusinesses();

  // Filter search

  $scope.filterOptions = function(){
    $scope.filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.categoryList, $scope.serviceList, $scope.businessList);
  };
}]);
```

**search.html**

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; height: 4em">
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper" style="margin-left: -0.5em;">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data" ng-change="filterOptions()">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-clear">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="result-list" ng-show="data.length > 0" style="margin-top: 3.9em" ng-model="data">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in categoryList | orderBy:'title'">{{item.title}}</li>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in serviceList | orderBy:'title'">{{item.title}}</li>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="item in businessList | orderBy:'title'">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the code for `filterSearch`? you also forgot to annotate it maybe that's why it is not working

Comment: *"what am I getting wrong"* ... how would we know? You haven't explained what you are trying to do , what isn't working amd what expected results are

Comment: @charlietfl I am expecting the search filter to function as it does here: http://codepen.io/asadfida/pen/znmCq to filter the items in `<ul class="list">`.

Comment: that doesn't explain a problem, or errors encountered. Also you haven't shown andy code for `filterSearch`

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry. I think its meant to be `filterFilter`. Updated question. Right now nothing happens when type text into the search field

Comment: @koox00 I've updated the question. Hopefully this clarifies things. Let me know please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to annotate you controller correctly.

e.g:

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', ["$scope", "ServicesData", "filterFilter" function($scope, ServicesData, filterFilter)  {
```

Second [`filterFilter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) takes as arguments, **one** array, an expression to filter that array and a comparator. Meaning you cannot pass just three arrays and expect some result.

If you want to filter all three arrays with one Input you have to call the filter function against each array separately. Or apply the filter directly in the `ng-repeat` of each `<li>`.

e.g:

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="item in filteredCategory = (categoryList | orderBy:'title' | filter:data )">{{item.title}}</li>
<li class="item" ng-repeat="item in filteredService = (serviceList | orderBy:'title' | filter:data)">{{item.title}}</li>
<li class="item" ng-repeat="item in filterredBussiness = (businessList | orderBy:'title' | filter:data)">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Keep in mind that this way you don't need the `ng-change` in the input.